# Black Screen With Cursor in Bootcamp

Tags: bootcamp, error

I installed a new bootcamp after a month and it worked fine, then I realized that I have low VRAM usage (128mb) and I tried to change it but failed but still everything was going fine until I closed my pc for a day.
After starting up again I couldn't open windows 10, it went black screen after the blue windows logo and i couldnt even open the task manager. I can change to my mac partition and use OS X but windows 10 is unusable. How can I fix this through OS X?

Comment: What did you change specifically? I've had this problem before as well.

Comment: i changed VRAM through regedit, using 4 cores instead of 1 and changed the limit